# How do I alphabetize and sub alphabetize this list?

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, how do I alphabetize and sub alphabetize this file?

http://see.weareinto.com/4UKn

*adding small sample of large HTML file.*

```
<div class="two-col" id="content_well">
    <ul class="hierarchyLeft3 filtererd">


        <li><a href=
            "/health-professionals/programs/center-for-outcomes-research-and-educati/Pages/default.aspx">
            Center for Outcomes Research and Education (CORE)</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="/health-professionals/programs/camp-erin/Pages/default.aspx">Camp
                Erin</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href=
                    "/health-professionals/programs/providence-hospice-bereavement-services/Pages/default.aspx">
                    Providence Hospice Bereavement Services</a></li>

                <li><a href=
                    "/health-professionals/programs/providence-home-services/Pages/default.aspx">Providence
                    Home Services</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href=
            "/health-professionals/programs/childrens-inpatient-care-unit/Pages/default.aspx">Children's
            Inpatient Care Unit</a></li>

        <li>
            <a href=
            "/health-professionals/programs/gerry-frank-center-for-childrens-care/Pages/default.aspx">
                Gerry Frank Center for Children's Care</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href=
                    "/health-professionals/programs/neurodevelopmental-center-for-children/Pages/default.aspx">
                    Providence Neurodevelopmental Center for Children</a></li>

                <li><a href=
                    "/health-professionals/programs/providence-pediatric-surgery/Pages/default.aspx">
                    Providence Pediatric Surgery</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href=
            "/health-professionals/programs/hodgkin-and-nonhodgkin-lymphoma-program/Pages/default.aspx">
            Hodgkin and Non-Hodgkin Lymphoma Program</a></li>

        <li><a href=
            "/health-professionals/programs/labor-delivery/Pages/default.aspx">Labor &amp;
            Delivery</a></li>

        <li><a href=
            "/health-professionals/programs/lifeline/Pages/default.aspx">Lifeline</a></li>

        <li><a href=
            "/health-professionals/programs/nicunewborn-care/Pages/default.aspx">NICU-Newborn
            Care</a></li>

        <li><a href=
            "/health-professionals/programs/omlc-cell-therapy-and-regenerative-medic/Pages/default.aspx">
            OMLC Cell Therapy and Regenerative Medicine Program</a></li>

        <li><a href=
            "/health-professionals/programs/omlc-hemorrhage-control-technology-progr/Pages/default.aspx">
            OMLC Hemorrhage Control Technology Program</a></li>

        <li><a href=
            "/health-professionals/programs/omlc-optics-program/Pages/default.aspx">OMLC Optics
            Program</a></li>

        <li><a href=
            "/health-professionals/programs/omlc-tropoelastin-biomaterials-program/Pages/default.aspx">
            OMLC Tropoelastin Biomaterials Program</a></li>

        <li>
            <a href=
            "/health-professionals/programs/oregon-medical-laser-center-omlc/Pages/default.aspx">
                Oregon Medical Laser Center (OMLC)</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href=
                    "/health-professionals/programs/omlc-cell-therapy-and-regenerative-medic/Pages/default.aspx">
                    OMLC Cell Therapy and Regenerative Medicine Program</a></li>

                <li><a href=
                    "/health-professionals/programs/omlc-hemorrhage-control-technology-progr/Pages/default.aspx">
                    OMLC Hemorrhage Control Technology Program</a></li>

                <li><a href=
                    "/health-professionals/programs/omlc-optics-program/Pages/default.aspx">OMLC
                    Optics Program</a></li>

                <li><a href=
                    "/health-professionals/programs/omlc-tropoelastin-biomaterials-program/Pages/default.aspx">
                    OMLC Tropoelastin Biomaterials Program</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href=
            "/health-professionals/programs/portland-diabetes-project/Pages/default.aspx">Portland
            Diabetes Project</a></li>

        <li><a href=
            "/health-professionals/programs/pregnancy-services/Pages/default.aspx">Pregnancy
            Services</a></li>

        <li>
            <a href=
            "/health-professionals/programs/providence-acute-rehabilitation-center/Pages/default.aspx">
                Providence Acute Rehabilitation Center</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href=
                    "/health-professionals/programs/providence-rehabilitation-services/Pages/default.aspx">
                    Providence Rehabilitation Services</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href=
            "/health-professionals/programs/adolescent-eating-disorders-program/Pages/default.aspx">
                Providence Adolescent Eating Disorders Program</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href=
                    "/health-professionals/programs/adult-eating-disorders-treatment-program/Pages/default.aspx">
                    Providence Adult Eating Disorders Treatment Program</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href=
            "/health-professionals/programs/adolescent-inpatient-behavioral-health-t/Pages/default.aspx">
                Providence Adolescent Inpatient Behavioral Health Treatment</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href=
                    "/health-professionals/programs/child-inpatient-behavioral-health-treatm/Pages/default.aspx">
                    Providence Child Inpatient Behavioral Health Treatment</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href=
            "/health-professionals/programs/adult-eating-disorders-treatment-program/Pages/default.aspx">
                Providence Adult Eating Disorders Treatment Program</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href=
                    "/health-professionals/programs/adolescent-eating-disorders-program/Pages/default.aspx">
                    Providence Adolescent Eating Disorders Program</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href=
            "/health-professionals/programs/providence-als-center/Pages/default.aspx">Providence
            ALS Center</a></li>

        <li><a href=
            "/health-professionals/programs/providence-arrhythmia-services/Pages/default.aspx">Providence
            Arrhythmia Services</a></li>

        <li>
            <a href=
            "/health-professionals/programs/autologous-stem-cell-transplant-program/Pages/default.aspx">
                Providence Autologous Stem Cell Transplant Program</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href=
                    "/health-professionals/programs/providence-cancer-center/Pages/default.aspx">Providence
                    Cancer Center</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href=
            "/health-professionals/programs/providence-behavioral-health/Pages/default.aspx">Providence
                Behavioral Health</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href=
                    "/health-professionals/programs/adolescent-eating-disorders-program/Pages/default.aspx">
                    Providence Adolescent Eating Disorders Program</a></li>

                <li><a href=
                    "/health-professionals/programs/adolescent-inpatient-behavioral-health-t/Pages/default.aspx">
                    Providence Adolescent Inpatient Behavioral Health Treatment</a></li>

                <li><a href=
                    "/health-professionals/programs/adult-eating-disorders-treatment-program/Pages/default.aspx">
                    Providence Adult Eating Disorders Treatment Program</a></li>

                <li><a href=
                    "/health-professionals/programs/behavioral-health-adult-inpatient-treatm/Pages/default.aspx">
                    Providence Behavioral Health Adult Inpatient Treatment</a></li>

                <li><a href=
                    "/health-professionals/programs/child-inpatient-behavioral-health-treatm/Pages/default.aspx">
                    Providence Child Inpatient Behavioral Health Treatment</a></li>

                <li><a href=
                    "/health-professionals/programs/psychiatric-dialectical-behavior-outpati/Pages/default.aspx">
                    Providence Psychiatric Dialectical Behavior Outpatient Therapy Program</a></li>

                <li><a href=
                    "/health-professionals/programs/psychiatric-intensive-outpatient-program/Pages/default.aspx">
                    Providence Psychiatric Intensive Outpatient Program</a></li>

                <li><a href=
                    "/health-professionals/programs/psychiatric-outpatient-partial-hospital-/Pages/default.aspx">
                    Providence Psychiatric Outpatient Partial Hospital Program</a></li>

                <li><a href=
                    "/health-professionals/programs/providence-psychiatry-clinic/Pages/default.aspx">
                    Providence Psychiatry Clinic</a></li>

                <li><a href=
                    "/health-professionals/programs/providence-substance-abuse-treatment/Pages/default.aspx">
                    Providence Substance Abuse Treatment</a></li>

                <li><a href=
                    "/health-professionals/programs/providence-youth-services/Pages/default.aspx">Providence
                    Youth Services</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Please post relevant information in the question. I can't access your file. At this point I can't tell what you're asking.

Comment: @patrickdw: Not that it's inaccessible, it's just HUGE.

Comment: @Brad: Were you able to get it? Chrome keeps complaining that the page has become unresponsive.

Comment: @patrickdw: Yes, it's UL's upon UL's of hyperlinks. -- may be a temp link, but right click->Save target this one: http://f.cl.ly/items/3v1x1Q3a0o0S1x421r2l/test.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to dive down and sort all lists and sublists at arbitrary depth, you could try something like this:

```
function sortItem(a, b) {
  return $.trim($(a).find('a').text()) > $.trim($(b).find('a').text()) ? 1 : -1;
}

function sortList(root) {
  $(root).children('li')
         .sort(sortItem)
         .appendTo(root)
         .children('ul')
         .each(function() {
           sortList(this); // recurse
  });
}

sortList('ul.hierarchyLeft3');
```

Working (highly reduced dataset) example: http://jsfiddle.net/redler/hwhrt/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
function sortAlpha(a,b){
    return a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML ? 1 : -1;
};

$('ol li').sort(sortAlpha).appendTo('ol');
```

Something like this?

Also, if this is a "ordered" list you should use ol ;)